# create more strict google api endpoint authentication

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-ruby-client

I've created an app on Google App Engine and now I'm moving on to security. I would like to lock it down to only a few Ruby clients. I can't seem to find anywhere that explains securing your endpoints for non iOS/Android/JavaScript files. I would like to use the authentication outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth) I just don't understand how to go about this for my Ruby app, or a client app trying to consume a their web api.

Comment: Is your endpoint created in Java?

Comment: I wrote it in python and would like a ruby client to use OAuth2.

Comment: The python equivalent docs URL is here, it has the steps required to enable authentication for the various methods https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth

Comment: That's fine but it doesn't tell me how to consume it with a http client, in my case ruby. They give me examples using their libraries. Unless I'm completely blind.

Comment: What I understand so far is that you can successfully make a call from ruby to an unauthenticated endpoint, but your issue is how to call an authenticated endpoint, is this correct?. I had to do something similar before, not with ruby, but will try to dig out the details

Answer (score 1):

On the GAE side you need to generate a client ID for native application and create an oAuth protected endpoint with the generated client ID populated in allowed_client_ids.

Here’s a sample Python endpoint:

```
import endpoints
import logging

from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote

CLIENT_ID = 'your_client_id_for_native_app'

class ServerRequestMSG(messages.Message):
    status = messages.StringField(1)

class ResponseMSG(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)

@endpoints.api(name='localcall', version='v0.1',
                allowed_client_ids=[CLIENT_ID, endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
                scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE],
                description='Local endpoints call test')
class LocalCallAPI(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(ServerRequestMSG, ResponseMSG,
                        path='authed', http_method='POST',
                        name='call.authed')
    def call_authed(self, request):
        current_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
        logging.info(request.status)
        email = (current_user.email() if current_user is not None
                 else 'Anonymous')
        return ResponseMSG(message='hello %s' % (email,))

app = endpoints.api_server([LocalCallAPI])
```

On the client side you need to get [Google API Ruby Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client). Then you can use this sample to make calls to your oAuth protected endpoint:

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'

# Initialize the client.
client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => 'your_local_app_name',
  :application_version => 'app_version',
  :host => 'your_app_id.appspot.com',
  :discovery_path => '/_ah/api/discovery/v1'
)

# Initialize API.
service = client.discovered_api('localcall', 'v0.1')

# Run installed application flow.
flow = Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow.new(
  :client_id => 'your_client_id_for_native_app',
  :client_secret => 'client_secret_from_console',
  :scope => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
)
client.authorization = flow.authorize

# Make an API call.
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => service.call.authed,
  :parameters => {'status' => 'hello'}
)
```

As you see, when making a call to your own API rather than Google's, you need to override host and discovery_path values and set API name and version. I don't think it is expressly documented, but library allows it and this can be deduced after examining the library source.